# Converting GeoTIFF into non-compressed format for WhiteBox?

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, mosaic, whitebox-gat

I am looking for an opensource solution to create a seamless air photo mosaic.

I came across WhiteBox from the University of Guelph which seems like it might do the trick, but it does not support GeoTiff Compression.

Is there a way to convert Geotiff's into a non-compressed format that WhiteBox would be able to use?

Answer (score 7):

Sure, gdal_translate:

> gdal_translate in_file.tif out_file.tif -co "PROFILE=GeoTIFF" -co "TFW=YES"

the above command should do the trick.

Comment: how do I use the command? Is there a GDAL interface or something else? I'm not familiar with GDAL

Comment: I wonder if I wrote an automated script that replied to all posts with say RASTER and CONVERT in it that said "Sure, gdal_translate" how much of the time it would be correct? One of my students asked if it was magic....

Comment: @rspencer38 I think you should research/ask that as a separate question.

Comment: @rspencer38: Its a command line tool. You use cmd.exe, or you find a GDAL GUI interface (e.g. QGIS :-))

Comment: @nickves why is this not compression = NONE http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html just curous

Comment: @Ifyoudonotknow-justGIS 'COMPRESS=NONE' is the default,  for the gtiff driver, so it's safe to omit.